# SQL query for data sorted and grouped by months

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am working on a way to display the order count for months at every single month in a given time span and some other limiting factors. Here is my query.

```
SELECT month(o.ord_date) as month, COUNT(o.ord_id) as January, COUNT(o.ord_id) as February, COUNT(o.ord_id) as March, COUNT(o.ord_id) as April, 
COUNT(o.ord_id) as May, COUNT(o.ord_id) as June, COUNT(o.ord_id) as July, COUNT(o.ord_id) as August, COUNT(o.ord_id) as September, 
COUNT(o.ord_id) as October, COUNT(o.ord_id) as November, COUNT(o.ord_id) as December
FROM hotels h, countries r, cities c, orders o LEFT JOIN trips t ON o.trp_id=t.trp_id
WHERE o.ord_date>'2016-01-01' AND o.ord_date<'2017-01-05' AND t.spr_id IN ('34','68','53')
      AND o.htl_id=h.htl_id AND h.ctr_id = r.ctr_id AND h.cty_id = c.cty_id AND r.ctr_id = 245
GROUP BY month(o.ord_date)
ORDER BY month ASC
```

I am looking for a result something like this:

```
        | Jan | Feb | March | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec
Jan     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Feb     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
March   |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Apr     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
May     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Jun     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Jul     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Aug     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Sept    |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Oct     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Nov     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
Dec     |  1  |  1  |   1   |  1  |  1  |   1 |  1  |  1  |   1  |  1  |  1  |   1
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here is orders table definition [P.Salmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon) requested:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `ord_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ord_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ord_deliv_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `trp_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `htl_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ord_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=35026 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

here is few fields that would need explaining:

1. `ord_date` date when the order was first made
2. `ord_deliv_date` date when the order should be delivered. In this case date when the trip (refernced in `trp_id`) will start.
3. `htl_id` is a reference to a hotel table where `ctr_id` and `cty_id` is stored.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: First replace implicit joins with explicit joins.

Comment: Can you add the table definition for orders please and some sample data.

Comment: why rows are columns are same .. looks weird  to me

Comment: I guess rows are date when order was made and columns date when order should be delivered?

Comment: thats correct, [P.Salmon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional aggregation may be what you need.
If we ignore the joins and conditions then

```
select month(ord_date),
sum(case when month(ord_deliv_date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
sum(case when month(ord_deliv_date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
.
.
sum(case when month(ord_deliv_date) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as Dec
from orders 
group by month(ord_date)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, sir!